# Magento 2, How copy and resize image of category atfer upload

Tags: category, magento2.2, gallery-image

Using `Magento 2`, `Admin`, `Catalog-Category`. I would like make an image which copy and resize after upload **category image**.

**Example:**

I upload image name : ***rest04.jpg*** 
magento will genterate : */pub/media/magestore/storelocator/images/store/gallery/r/e/**rest04.jpg***
, so I need an image which name "/pub/media/magestore/storelocator/images/store/gallery/**size_40_40**/r/e/**rest04.jpg**".